# How to use query string routing in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want this type of url use in `CodeIgniter` and get value of id
http://example.com/web/index.php/abcd/xyz?id=NTAz

How can I get the value of id and how to set route in `CodeIgniter` 3.

Comment: [How can I read a QueryString in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397100/how-can-i-read-a-querystring-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a QueryString in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397100/how-can-i-read-a-querystring-in-codeigniter)