# querystring makes codeigniter fail

Tags: codeigniter, query-string

I'm using Codeigniter with the mvc, and I'm not using querystrings, but I have this api call to facebook, that returns a querystring.

Only thing is that when I get it back with `site.com/controller/method?state=supm&code=supm`
I get a 310, because I'm not setup to handle querystrings. I can't change the config['uri_protocol'] to 'PATH_INFO', because then only my main page will get displayed, and none of the mvc parameteres will get interpreted (for some reason), so how can I make my page not fail, and still get the code and state from facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$this->input->get()` (see [Input Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)), just making sure you have `allow_get_array` set to TRUE in your config.php file.

I believe this item was added in CI 2.0 and is on by default, so it now allows you to access GET data without needing to use `enable_query_strings`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [enabling query strings](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

If you still like to preserve your old urls (site/controller/function/parameters), you'll have to insert a hook. [This one](https://github.com/dhorrigan/codeigniter-query-string) looks fine (haven't tested it myself though).

Edit:
Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171185/codeigniter-php-framework-need-to-get-query-string).

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it's a little drastic to change the entire pattern because I have a service that returns a querystring. i would rather do it the other way round. Preserve the uri segment pattern and then allow querystrings, or do you think that's not possible?

Comment: You don't have to enable query strings to access the query values. I believe it was CI 2.0 where `$config['allow_get_array']` was introduced.

Comment: Jakob, yes, it's possible, either by the second example I gave you or regularly if you're using CI2, like Mike said
@Mike You don't know if he's using CI2 or older, no reason to give a minus for that.