# Not able to get data from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have below query 
`http://localhost/barbadosparliament/result/index?qry=testing`
Now i want ot get data of qry parameter from url. But not able to get data. I used $this->uri->segment and also $_GET['qry']. But still i doesn't get that record. How can i get that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check you have on in config/config.php

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```

then try

```
$qry = $this->input->get('qry', TRUE);
$qry = $_GET['qry'];
$qry = $_REQUEST['qry'];
```

Also try url like

http://localhost.com/barbadosparliament/result?qry=testing

Comment: are you getting this on controller result/ function index?

Comment: function index()
 {
                 echo    $this->input->get('qry'); 
                 echo $qry = $_GET['qry'];
                 echo $qry = $_REQUEST['qry'];
                 die;
 }

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171185/codeigniter-php-framework-need-to-get-query-string

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$qry = $this->input->get('qry');
```

But this should works too

```
$qry = $_GET['qry'];
```