# Get the value from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

In this URL: `www.example.com/transaction/summary/10` I can get `10` by this:

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

But, along with some other `GET` params how can I get that value?

e.g.: `www.example.com/transaction/summary?local_branch=1/10`

PS: `GET` params could be more than 1.

Comment: If you would like to use codeigniter input features http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get

Comment: Did u checked solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To get these GET parameters you can just use:

`$this->input->get('some_variable', TRUE);`

As per the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171185/codeigniter-php-framework-need-to-get-query-string) here.

`example.com/?some_variable=hey`

Comment: Your link says "documentation" but it's just a link to another SO answer which contains the actual link to the documentation.

Comment: U didnt respond on answers

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep `CI` style than add segments:

**URL:**

```
www.example.com/transaction/summary/10/1/TEST
```

**Segments:**

```
$this->uri->segment(3); // 10
$this->uri->segment(4); // 1
$this->uri->segment(5); // TEST
```

Or if you want to use query string than you can add params in query string and get values by using `$_GET`:

```
www.example.com/transaction/summary/10/?local_branch=1&test=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, segments in Codeigniter are the content between slashs like mysite.com/page/page-name. To get the page-name value I get the second segment, or `$this->uri->segment(1)`. To get the strings passed by query string ($_GET), you can simply use the `$_GET['local_branch']` as in your example or in case of Codeigniter, as the @Tom answer: `$this->input->get('local_branch')`.

In this case, you can to explode the values delimiting by **/**.

```
$localBranch = $_GET['local_branch'];

// Or
$localBranch = $this->input->get('local_branch');

// And split using the / as delimiter if is need.
$localBranch = explode('/', $localBranch);

// Output
// Array(0 => 1, 1 => 10)
```

This way many values can be passed in same query string.