# 404 error in codeigniter 3 when calling controller without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3.

I created login controller like

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
     public function index()
     {
          echo "It's working";
     }
}
?>
```

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also enabled rewrite module.

It is working on

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/login
```

but not on

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/login
```

How can I solve this issue. or its bug in codeigniter 3.0.4
Please help.

Comment: What localhost you using xampp, wamp?

Comment: On your config.php have you made this like so `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 xampp , in config.php I have `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

Comment: try this config!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171185/codeigniter-php-framework-need-to-get-query-string/33965523#33965523

Comment: @AldoZumaran  Got this error Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost

Comment: create a virtual host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mod_rewrite rules are redirecting to */index.php* instead of */codeigniter/index.php*.

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /codeigniter/
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is still not working, you might want to check you httpd conf to make sure Override for .htaccess is allowed because AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files. Invariably, if you place settings in the .htaccess file and you do not AllowOverride for those settings, the dafault Apache settings would still run and everything in your .htaccess would not be used. For example

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName application.co

  DocumentRoot "/Users/www/htdocs/application/"
  ErrorLog "/Users/www/logs/application_error.log"



  <Directory "/Users/www/htdocs/application/" >
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Allow from localhost, application.co
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in config/config.php

Comment: thanks for answer I tried `$config['index_page'] = '';` but not working

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] `

try it in htaccess in place of


`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: are you use server in linux? mean xampp or wamp ?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and xampp, @ZohaibHassan its not working

Comment: have you restart xampp after enabling `rewrite_module`??

Comment: i will suggest to check again `rewrite_module` and `url_rewriting` issue and please complete these four steps in following link and also resstart xampp after it..
http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for `uri_protocol` does not work properly. 
Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

> HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: are you replace .htaccess with this bcz its worked for me

Comment: Ya I did but not working, is it a bug in codeigniter? @MayankVadiya

Comment: No not a bug. What is your url

Comment: @MayankVadiya there is no AUTO in CI3 uri_protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can try this htaccess i use on xampp.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Place in main directory of project.

And on config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And make sure your class and file names have first letter upper case as explained [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world).

Also for more htaccess [Here](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)