# CodeIgniter: How to add multiple parameters with clean url?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having a filter options with below setting:

Option 1 > **Show:** 20 per page or 50 per page or All per page - This is in a drop down (Default 10 per page)

Option 2 > **Sort by:** Low to High or High to Low or Alphabetic A-Z or Alphabetic Z-A (Default A-Z)

Option 3 > **Pagination** This is done.

My landing page is: *domain-name/shirts*

I have done the pagination and my url looks like: *domain-name/shirts/page/1*

The url I want to achieve:  *domain-name/shirts/page/1/perpage/50/sortby/Z-A*

**But in real world the end-user select this options in different way:**

**Scenario 1:**
Example: Sort by first, and then page number second, url example: *domain-name/shirts/perpage/50/page/1**

(OR)

**Scenario 2:**
Example: Sort by first and then page number second, url example: *domain-name/shirts/perpage/50/page/1*

(OR)

**Scenario 3:**
Example: Sort by first and then page number second, url example: *domain-name/shirts/sortby/Z-A/perpage/50/page/1*

I would like the url structure to be in the following order, all the time - doesn't matter how these options are selected:

1. *domain-name/shirts/page/1/sortby/Z-A*
2. *domain-name/shirts/page/1/perpage/50/*
3. *domain-name/shirts/perpage/50/sortby/Z-A*
4. *domain-name/shirts/page/1/perpage/50/sortby/Z-A*

How do I achieve this?

**My Controller code - index()**

```
            $all_shirts = $this->shirts_model->get_shirts_count();
    $total_rows = $all_shirts;

    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."shirts";
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;        
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = false;
    $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
    $config['first_url'] = '1';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['first_url'] = base_url().'shirts';
    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next >';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = ' <span class="next">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config['prefix'] = '/page/';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<span class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span> ';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = ' <b>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';
    if($this->uri->segment(3) < '3')
    {
        $config['prev_link'] = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $config['prev_link'] = '< Previous';
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data = array();
    $data['Shirts_pagination'] = $this->shirts_model->get_shirts_limit($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3,0),'');
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['show_all'] = 0;
    $this->load->view('shirts_view.php', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in all your example you have to get the `$this->uri->segment()` from the url to filter .

I really do not use so many url params, i think cleaner url could be great also for you.

For any additional filter param i use session and post data from the form.

So my urls always looks like having 2 or max 3 params, for example:

```
users/list/23
```

where `23 = pagination offset /*it could be also page number if you want*/`

in addition i sometimes use category uri segment for example:

```
users/list/woman/23
```

but i always try to leave url really short and cleaner, putting all additional filter params into the session which is hidden to the url.

Usually , let's make the example , page is a search page, where users are listed, i create a form for search users :

```
 - input text for username searching
 -- 1 button for ordering newest users
 -- 1 button for ordering oldest users
 --- 1 input type submit for submitting all the search form
```

now, once you sumbit search form you just check if `$this->input->post('ordering'); -> create session value for ordering`, so next time you will load the prev or next page the value of ordering is the same you setted up.

I'll need about 100K lines to make an example you can anyway google how to make search and pagination in Codeigniter and filters params. I'm sure you will catch some good tutorial ;)

HERE some one more resource, just google ;)

[Filter, sort and paginate in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428651/filter-sort-and-paginate-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Hi Okok, can you explain in depth with some example, how to do these with sessions and achieve short urls, please?

Comment: @sapppy :D i'm really tyred anyway it's really simple, do you know how to use session? what is session? how CI use sessions?

Comment: I have some knowledge on sessions. I am learning my first CI MVC framework so, I don't know how this works in CI. I will try and see if I can find anything on google. Thanks