# How to display results so back button does not ask to reload POST variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers

I have a form that uses XML to get results. From those results users can click to a detail page. My problem is when a user clicks back to the results page, they are asked if they want to submit the form again. How do I create this so back button just displays the results, like on aa.com, ebay, autotrader, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660329/prevent-back-button-from-showing-post-confirmation-alert

Comment: The actual solution: The ["Post/Redirect/Get Pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) - If you `header('Location: /someotherpage.php");` in response to the post - it will not ask the user to resubmit post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your page move the $_POST variables into the $_SESSION array and then header redirect the user to the results page.

Comment: Don't use SESSION. This risks race conditions.

Comment: That is only when using AJAX - i.e. in a pseudo multi threaded environment. It's totally safe otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect to another page to using [redirect()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) method of codeigniter. This will prevent the browser asking a confirmation on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a search page that displays results? Why not use GET rather than POST in your form?  Looking at search engines out there, they seem to use GET for their search interface.  I can think of a few reasons to use GET rather than POST.

- If the operation simply fetches results, semantically, the GET method is more appropriate.  GET is used when you are fetching data. POST is more used when you are submitting a change to the application.
- If you use GET, clicking on the back button won't give you a dialog asking whether you wish to resubmit the form.
- Your users will have a URL directly to a search results page for a particular query that they can share.

Unfortunately CodeIgniter, by default, nukes the query string when processing a request.  You can enable the query string in CodeIgniter by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043070/enabling-get-in-codeigniter/2281764#2281764).