# Htaccess Codeigniter problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, paypal

I used an htaccess in my project that use Codeigniter framework:

DirectoryIndex index.php

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My problem is, when i call a paypal service, Paypal response for me an GET url, like that:
http://xxx.xx.com/myproject/paypalCallback?tx=32J30607S6157364F&st=Pending&amt=85.00&cc=SGD&cm=&item_number=

I receive a 404 page not found. Htaccess doesn't accept GET URL: ?tx=32J30607S6...
I sure it's work on local, but not on live side

If you can, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! please format your code correctly. Thanks! To learn how to do so , click on the orange question mark http://i.i.imgur.com/BApIf.png

Comment: What version of CI are you using? Have a look in the config file for the url parameter settings.

Comment: the url without the query string (what follows the `?`) works ?

Comment: What happens if you change the config file to accept query stings? It's off by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this works in CI

you can still access query string if they are disable in CI, try this code

## To remove index.php from URL

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

if you have CI app in sub directories use this

```
RewriteBase /f2f/f2fweb
```

Comment: you must use your own directories :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may work that you can try is putting a plain php file in your base directory called paypalcallback.php or something along those lines with the following code:

```
$tx  = $_GET['tx'];
$st  = $_GET['st'];
$amt = $_GET['amt'];
... etc ...

header("location:/myproject/papalCallback/$tx/$st/$amt");
exit;
```

It basically reads query strings and converts to url segments.  Generally it's easier than messing with the query strings and creating fancy rewrite rules.  I use it for linking to a image manager in CKeditor, because it requires a querystring variable in the callback.

I guess most of this would depend on whether or not the http header code matters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable query string in application/config/config.php or enabled '?' character in $config['permitted_uri_chars']

Answer (score 0):

Related:

[CodeIgniter PHP Framework - Need to get query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171185/codeigniter-php-framework-need-to-get-query-string)

[Enabling $_GET in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043070/enabling-get-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks all of you, my friends,

I try to follow all your posts. And finaly, I found the correct way for my case, it's very simple.
I change htacces file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

You see, i insert '?' before '/'. It's will accept my URL ..paypalCallback/?tx=123213.

It's work. May be I'm lucky ^ ^

Anyway, thanks for your help

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me after googling for few hours :

1. In application/config/config.php i used this change

   ```
     $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
     $config['index_page'] = "";
   ```
2. In .htaccess

   ```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|application|media|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
   ```
3. In   /system/libraries/URI.php

   ```
    Replace

       if ( ! preg_match("|^[".preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'))."]+$|i", $str))

    With

       if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace('\\-', '-', preg_quote ($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars')))."]+$|i", $str))
   ```

That's it. I took one of these solution from http://dragffy.com/blog/posts/codeigniter-17-the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters