# CodeIgniter $this->input->get() not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not sure why this is not working. I have allow_get_array = TRUE in the config file. Here's what I am trying to do..

This is the link that the user will click from their email

```
http://www.site.com/confirm?code=f8c53b1578f7c05471d087f18b343af0c3a638
```

confirm.php Controller:

```
$code = $this->input->get('code');
```

also tried

```
$code = $this->input->get('code', TRUE);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043070/enabling-get-in-codeigniter

Comment: @darin-kolev When I change to PATH_INFO my views load into each other...have no clue why

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043070/enabling-get-in-codeigniter?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this and it worked without having to change the config file:

```
//put some vars back into $_GET.
parse_str(substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?"), 1), $_GET);

// grab values as you would from an ordinary $_GET superglobal array associative index.
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

Comment: @CollinsAbitekaniza, but it is codeigniter method, and it doesn't clean XSS

Answer (score 8):

In your `config.php` change the following:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

To:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Instead of messing with Query Strings you could change your URI to use segments like `http://www.site.com/confirm/code/f8c53b1578f7c05471d087f18b343af0c3a638`. To access the code segment you would use `$this->uri->segment(3);`. Personally I prefer this way as to using Query Strings. See [URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: @KraigBalla Take a look at my updated answer, I always seem to have better luck when I use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `AUTO`, also I added a quick suggestion for how I would go about this using URI segments.

Comment: With this approach you can put the application in risk, because you're breaking routing rules.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : NULL;
```

**EDIT:**

In PHP >=7.0, you can do this:

```
$code = $_REQUEST['code'] ?? NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try

```
http://www.site.com/confirm/?code=f8c53b1578f7c05471d087f18b343af0c3a638
```

instead of

```
http://www.site.com/confirm?code=f8c53b1578f7c05471d087f18b343af0c3a638
```

without any config or else edit please