# Why this codeigniter function parameter isn't working as it should be?

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, coinbase-api

I'm trying to create callback script for Coinbase bitcoin payments. Here is the below function from my payment controller. But somehow the key isn't working as it should. I am trying to access it like that: `http://www.example.com/payments/callback?key=true` but it's not getting affected basically not working. **Take a note that the script is working itself but after adding the key function and validating it ... it's not anymore. The issue is caused by that but I don't know what exactly, so what may cause that in the script below?**
Thanks for taking the time to check and possibly answer my question.

```
function is_valid_key($key) {
    // logic to check key
    $valid = true;
    if($valid) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
}    

function callback()
    {
        //Check if key is valid.

        $key = $this->input->get('key');
        if( ! $this->is_valid_key($key)) {

        //If key above is valid order is "completed", please proceed.

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

        $status = $data['order']['status'];
        $userid = '507';

        if (($status === 'completed')) {
            $this->db->query( 'update users set user_money=user_money+15, user_credits=user_credits+5 WHERE users_id=' . $userid );
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has to do with your configuration settings. check out this question [Enabling $_GET in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043070/enabling-get-in-codeigniter)

Also you can  use

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
```

which would push GET right back on

Comment: Is there any way to do that as I simply need specific parameter to secure my script for being access by unathorized source. So, by adding any secret/key I can achieve this. Any other option for that to apply that parameter? or can I use `$this->uri->segment( 3 );` for example ?

Comment: @MobEn you can also use parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
which would push GET right back on